# How do I connect to Docker, running on host VMs in a Kubernetes cluster from a container running in the same Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-cronjob

I'm using a docker image that has docker installed inside it, in order to run tasks to cleanup docker image data on every node in my kubernetes cluster. I tried using Daemonset as it will run on each node except master, but running cron inside docker container proved fruitless.

Hence, I'm trying to use a K8s Cronjob, that runs periodically, with the attributes:

`hostNetwork: true`

and

```
      volumes:
        - name: dockersocket
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

I'm running a shell script that runs docker commands from within the container created by the above CronJob.

However, When i try and get all images running on a node of the kubernetes cluster using `docker -H X.X.X.X images` where X.X.X.X is the IP of one node in the k8s cluster, I get the following error:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://X.X.X.X:2375. Is the docker daemon running?`

Am I doing something wrong?
How do I connect to Docker running on the nodes of the kubernetes cluster from a container running inside the kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 2):

[Frame challenge](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/whats-a-frame-challenge/6843#6843): what you're doing is not the right approach.

Trying to access the underlying Docker in a Kubernetes cluster is *usually* viewed as a bad idea, as it can easily result in a corrupt state that's difficult to repair.

Kubelet has [built-in garbage collection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/). Why not tweak the configuration for that instead?

If you're running on one of the big PaaS providers, your node turnover will likely be high enough (from auto-upgrades/whatever else) that this isn't an issue regardless.